# when the computed column will update?

Tags: sql-server-2008, calculated-columns

I have computed column in table called "Claim" and  definition of column is calling one scalar function.

I created a 10000 claims so when i select those 10000 claims the computed column will update are when 10000 rows inserting itself the computed column will execute?

Please update me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the computed column marked as `persisted` or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends if the computed column is marked as `persisted` or is indexed.

If neither of these conditions are true then nothing is stored and it is calculated at runtime. Otherwise it is automatcally updated when the underlying data changes.

Answer (score 1):

The computed column computes its value when you execute a `SELECT` command that includes the column, assuming that the computed column's value is not `PERSISTED`.