# unrequired update in referenced table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have two tables one is for Egg sales to customers and another has a list of prices.

Everything is working perfectly except when I update the price list, when I update the price in pricelist I don't want the calculated price in old records to change. But in my case if I update the pricelist, old entries also change which is not correct for payments already done

Example

```
- **price_type**       **price_amount**
    big_eggs_tray             500    
   small_eggs_tray           250
```

and say I do a sale of 2 eggs to my customer. Which makes my sales table look like this

```
id    customer_name  price_type       eggs/trays   total  amount_paid  remaining
11    Bob            big_eggs_tray       2         1000       250          750
```

Now when I update  the price list table I don't want my old records to change.
how do I achieve this.

Please help my application is all done but I have run into this bug on testing phase.
I'm using SQL Server and ASP.NET

Comment: Your old records aren't updating themselves.   Either your asp code behind is sending calls to the database or the database has a calculated field or a trigger on update or something like that.

Comment: Please post the list of columns in your Price List table. If the Price List table has any unique indexes, that would be useful information as well.

Comment: Well i managed to solve it.  But here is a list of columns in price list ** price_id, price_type,amount, description ....  But what i did to solve is i added start and end date column.  And so i wont be updating prices but rather old ones will expire and i will be able to maintain their values in both price list table and sales table.  Is there an alternative solution guys.  I would like to know.

Comment: @steve wellens.  There was no trigger tht i programmed but it was an automatic one because as u said the total column is a calculated column so whatever update i made to price list it was being reflected on the sales table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would you make sure that you are not updating the the fields which the calculating field dependent on? 
also, please have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328211/3316279